# Ebook and PDF reader that syncs bookmarks across OS X and Android

Tags: pdf, ebooks

I've been looking for an ebook and PDF reader which allows for bookmarking, and the synchronization of these bookmarks on my Android KitKat smartphone. The ability to have a black background (for ebooks) is preferred but not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Google Play Books]

Try [Google Play Books](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.books).  In May of 2013, the Google Play Books system was updated so that "you can upload your own files to Google Play Books to access on your Android, iOS and the web."([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OZ4q.png))

> After uploading your files, you can enjoy reading them with all the nice features
>   available: bookmarks, highlights and notes, dictionary and more. What’s more, your
>   reading progress, highlights etc are synced to the cloud, so if you have multiple 
>   devices, you can easily pick up reading anywhere!

Also, in Google Play Books for Android's settings, you can change the theme to "Night" in order to give you a black background.

- [Google Play Books Uploads](https://play.google.com/books/uploads)

[image: Google Play Books uploads image]